# What do paternity test restriction laws aim to achieve?

Tags: law, germany, france, feminism

I recently learned that genetic paternity tests are being restricted or even banned in Germany and France (and perhaps in other countries as well).

[In Germany the law requires consent from both parents](https://www.welt.de/politik/deutschland/article6049645/Heimliche-Vaterschaftstests-sind-nun-verboten.html) (so it's not a total ban) and in France [paternity tests can only be ordered by a judge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_paternity_testing#France).

What are the implications of these laws and why were they created in the first place? How does alimony work if it can not be proven who the biological father is?

Comment: Remember that reliable paternity tests are a young invention. Long before they came about, rules were developed to determine the (legal) father of a child, and those rules are still in place. If you are interested in what those rules are in France or Germany, you could ask questions on Law.SE.

Comment: Good point. It seems in the past there were different methods, but less accurate.

Comment: Mind you, the new German law is actually an improvement over the old one, which required the father to terminate his legal relationship with the child *before* asking for a test: https://www.dw.com/en/anxious-fathers-welcome-new-paternity-test-law/a-3142893 Back then "According to German Justice Minister Brigitte Zypries, some 20,000 secret tests are taken every year."

Comment: And related: http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-09-02/german-cuckoo-kids-law-punishes-women/7805370

Comment: And (state mandated--how else) paternity testing is related to immigration: https://www.dw.com/en/german-government-pushes-law-aimed-at-stopping-migrant-paternity-sale-scams/a-38309110

Comment: Note that the law is absolutely impossible to enforce in practice. Anyone can order a 23andMe kit and get a completely anonymous DNA test if they wish.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "why" in these cases would seem to be

1. The protection of the child is the primary consideration
2. However, there is a general right to privacy and a right not to have 
   one's DNA analysed.
3. Paternity testing in particular reveals private information not only about the person taking the test, but also the child's mother and third parties. This information can put mothers at risk of violence.

These rights need to weighed against each other, and only a judge can do that.

For genetic testing in general the law has evolved to establish that employers or insurers cannot require a person to have a genetic test that could prevent them from getting a job or health insurance.

In the case of paternity testing, a person cannot be required to take a paternity test, unless a judge decides that it is necessary for the protection of a child. The situation where a person collects a DNA sample without knowledge or consent is considered unacceptable.

However if there are two people who are potentially the father of a child. Then a paternity test taken by one will imply the paternity of the other. In French law (which generally places a higher value on privacy) this is seen as unacceptable unless it required for the protection of a child.

One particular concern is of the risk of "honour" violence against women. This seems to be a factor in the banning of paternity testing in some countries. Women have been murdered for committing adultery, and a paternity test may provide evidence of adultery.

There is also a concern that DNA testing done by a kit, or in an unregulated lab will be of low quality, and give erroneous results.

Alimony doesn't always require proof of biological parentage. For example, an adoptive father can be required to pay alimony. A man who has had parental responsibility for many years can be required to contribute to his presumed children, even if they turn out not to be genetically related. This is a matter for a Judge to decide, on the principle that children should be protected. Where the biological parenthood does need to be determined, the Judge can still order the paternity test.

Comment: -1. This seems like pure opinion (backed by misandrist dogma) - especially the "violence" thing that offensively implies that men are an inherently violent threat. There have been cases of a lot of things done by lots of people - there aren't laws preventing everyone doing everything just on the basis of "there were cases" (there were cases of women murdering their husbands to get their money. Yet nobody bans wives from automatically inheriting from the husband)

Comment: Additionally, the whole "privacy" thing is again just a convinient excuse. If that was a real reason, 100% sufficient would be the law that said "in cases of paternity testing, NO information is permitted to be revealed other than paternity % chance"; with the rest of genetic info covered by standard genetic testing law.

Comment: The question was "why have france and germany enacted these laws". The reasons appear to be the ones I give. If you don't like those reasons, please don't blame me. I didn't write the law in France. I'm just trying to answer the question.  If you think there is another reason, please answer the question yourself.

Comment: "There have been cases of men using the result of a paternity test to assault or even murder their wives."  This is a bit confusing.  It sounds like the result is a large bludgeoning object rather than a piece of information delivered on a sheet of paper.  Instead of "using", perhaps "reacting to" would make more sense.  E.g. "There have been cases of men reacting to the result of a paternity test by assaulting or even murdering their wives."  Or some other edit that makes plain that the result is the triggering event, not the weapon.

Comment: @JamesK - the reason only "appears" to be that way if you look at it uncritically. The only benefit of this law **that can't be achieved by far less draconian measures** is to help defraud men easier. (imagine a law that says that a woman can demand a random man to pay child support for her child. This would "improve the welfare of the child" too, and has about as much ethics about it as the consequence of this law - actually, more ethics, as it wouldn't be fraudulent)

Comment: @JamesK You could deflect the accusations that you have an agenda by finding some quotes from the politicians who supported these laws and frame your answer as stating their opinion and not your own.

Comment: Good references are hard to come by. I've seen lots of discussion, but my French isn't good enough to read the original. French Law tends to state the rules, but not the reasoning behind the rules (as is common in Civil Law countries). I've tried to summarise the reasoning discussed on multiple sites.  I'm surprised by the heat of the discussion. It seems to me that there are a number of reasonable positions that a country could take. France is at one end of that spectrum, the USA is at the other. I understand both positions, but the question was about France. So the answer is about France.

Comment: German laws and their amendments come with a separate document detailing the reasoning. (But it’s in German, of course.)

Comment: Do you have any links to discussions or sources? Even if in French or German, would be very helpful!

Comment: @user4012 the Question was about what the laws aim to achieve, not whether the laws respect men's rights, not whether the laws or just, and not whether the laws reflect the worst instincts of society. While it's clear the laws come from a very evil place in the souls of humankind, that wasn't what the question asked.

Comment: Protection of the child is NOT primary consideration, incidence of child abuse is way higher for children living with non-biological parents and anyone with minimal common sense will understand that forcing someone to parent a child that isn't his is not gonna do any good for anyone.

Comment: @user4012: The argument that the law would allow a woman to name a random man as the child has a couple barriers; 1.) That the person they name would refer to someone they definitely don't know, but could somehow get their name at random, 2.) That the woman would have confidence that a man they chose a name at random would have the funds to pay for child support. It's more likely to be someone they know, that they are at least *pretty sure* is the father.

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st - that wasn't the argument. The argument was that they are somewhat equivalent - they both allow - let's be honest, they **encourage** - unscrupulous women to defraud innocent male victims

Comment: I'm still amazed at two things.  Firstly that anyone believes that the **aim** of these laws is to encourage "unscrupulous women to defraud innocent men". And I'm amazed at the depths of the misogynistic mindset that argues that will "demand a random man to pay child support."  In my opinion the **aims** of the laws follows from a couple of axioms of the family courts:  "Child protection is the priority", and "Privicy matters".

Comment: Alimony has nothing to do with parentage, it is spousal support.

Comment: @user4012: On top of what James. K said - at the absolute weirdly specific edge cases that you're implying, that's where a judge would be involved. It wouldn't encourage that behaviour - at worse, it makes it slightly more safer to temporarily attempt following a judicial correction.

Comment: @JamesK - the cornerstone of most modern postmodernist/progressive political ideology and philosophy is very specifically that intent **does not matter** and only effects matter. As such, whether the intent of the laws is to encourage fraud, or not, is wholly irrelevant - only the fact that they do in the result encourage fraud, by making it easier and safer to perpetuate. I'll even allow that in some cases this fraud isn't even intentional on a mother's part, at least initially. Point is, they make it impossible for the fraud victim to defend themselves.

Comment: And yes, the privacy angle, as someone pointed out, is a complete and utter BS. Have the results sealed by the court, no more privacy issue. Done. And that is even disregarding issues like the fact that protecting privacy of a wrong-doer at the dramatic expense to the innocent victim is severely unjust. The "low quality test" is also wholly BS, as test can be ordered by court to be re-done at certified lab. Not to mention I have NEVER heard of low quality unreliable paternity tests.

Comment: yeah yeah,  I know your opinion of the tests.  What is unbelievable is that you think fraud is that aim.  That the world is so anti-man that laws are created *for the purpose* of fraud.   Poor men, if only we had a few more men in positions of leadership this terrible injustice could never have happened (irony)